# AngularJS md-select Ties two select values together

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a multi-select in angular where one of the elements in the array being selected from is a clone of another element in the array. This cloned element has some fields changed in it.

```
<md-select ng-model="$ctrl.modbusMeterDataParameters.points"
           md-on-close="$ctrl.unitSelect()" multiple no-dirty>
  <md-option ng-repeat="point in $ctrl.getPoints()" ng-value="point">
    {{point.name}}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Originally I was getting a `$$hashkey` error but I fixed this by adding `track by` to my `md-option` tag:

```
<md-option ng-repeat="point in $ctrl.getPoints() track by point.name"
           ng-value="point">
    {{point.name}}
</md-option>
```

But there is still an angular generated field on the points called `$$mdselectid` that is the same for the original element and the cloned element. I am creating the cloned element as follows:

```
this.filteredPoints = this.filterAndSortPoints(this.points);
const threePhaseDataPoint = _.cloneDeep(this.filteredPoints[0]);
threePhaseDataPoint.name = this.fullMeterDataLabel;
this.filteredPoints.push(threePhaseDataPoint);
```

I am currently getting around the problem by doing this:

```
if (threePhaseDataPoint.$$mdSelectId) {
    threePhaseDataPoint.$$mdSelectId = this.filteredPoints.length * 2;
}
```

But this seems very hacky. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: The [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) function will clone objects and omit properties that start with a dollar (`$`) sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `_.cloneDeep` with [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy):

```
this.filteredPoints = this.filterAndSortPoints(this.points);
̶c̶o̶n̶s̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶r̶e̶e̶P̶h̶a̶s̶e̶D̶a̶t̶a̶P̶o̶i̶n̶t̶ ̶=̶ ̶_̶.̶c̶l̶o̶n̶e̶D̶e̶e̶p̶(̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶f̶i̶l̶t̶e̶r̶e̶d̶P̶o̶i̶n̶t̶s̶[̶0̶]̶)̶;̶
const threePhaseDataPoint = angular.copy(this.filteredPoints[0]);
threePhaseDataPoint.name = this.fullMeterDataLabel;
this.filteredPoints.push(threePhaseDataPoint);
```

The [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) function clones objects and omits properties that start with a dollar (`$`) sign. This will force `md-select` to generate new internal variables.